# Getting email on daily basis, when ever we receive new object in S3 on daily basis - report in csv format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

I have a requirment were i need to send out a report on daily basis, list of files landing in my s3 bucket by EOD.

Is there a way to do it ?

I tried inventory option but it creates file in another S3 bucket in same region.

Comment: You could use an [S3 Event Notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventNotifications.html) on the bucket with the inventory report to trigger a Lambda to generate the report you're after.

Comment: Do you want the email to only contain the files added since the previous day? Approximately how many objects are created  each day and how many existing objects are in the bucket? I ask because it might be simpler to simply list the bucket and check the `LastModified` date, but that can be slow if there are thousands of objects.

Comment: we receive around 5 to 6 objects on a daily basis... Currently we have 20 objects in the bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do this by adding an s3 event notification on the bucket with an inventory report to trigger a lambda to generate a report - this helps.